# How to test DAO connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a mySql database and am using phpMyAdmin to manage it. I've written a simple JDBC DAO to test it, however it will not return any data.

I have double and triple checked the strings used by the DriverManager.getConnection function, they are the exact same as the ones I use to login through phpMyAdmin.

Is there an easier way to check if my DAO can actually connect, ie within the DAO itself instead of using a servlet like I'm doing?

```
//above this I have my imports, and username and password string
public Car getCar(int vin){
    Car c = null;
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM carList WHERE vin=" + vin);
        if(rs.next()){
            c = new Car();
            c.setVin(rs.getInt(1));
            c.setMake(rs.getString(2));
            c.setMake(rs.getString(3));
            c.setYear(rs.getInt(4));
            c.setTransmission(rs.getString(5));
            c.setFuelType(rs.getString(6));
            c.setColour(rs.getString(7));
            c.setDoors(rs.getInt(8));
            c.setPrice(rs.getInt(9));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex){

    } finally{
        try{
            if (stmt != null)
            {
                stmt.close();
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(carDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Simple servlet to return some info of a particular car in my database. It will print the line "details" but nothing else. I have tried overwriting the default toString method in the Car class too.

```
//imports etc above here
public class DAOTester extends HttpServlet {
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet DAOTester</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        carDAO dao = new carDAO();
        Car c = dao.getCar(35673451);
        out.print("details ");
        out.print(c.toString());
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may know the problem if you add `Logger.getLogger(CarDAO.class).error("Error on getCar", ex)` in `catch (SQLException ex)`.

Comment: I tried this but it won't compile properly, "Class<carDAO> cannot be converted to String"

Comment: Oh ok, then it should be `Logger.getLogger(CarDAO.class.getName()).error("Error on getCar", ex) in catch (SQLException ex)`.